# How to get authentication to access google services with android?

Tags: android

In my application I am interfacing with google services such as calendar and documents.  For testing I have just been providing a user name and password to access services as follows...

```
myService.setUserCredentials(username,password);
```

This method, at least how I'm implementing it, requires that I request the username and password for each session, which obviously is not practical.  I would prefer not to save the username or password in long term storage.  I know there is an account manager class in the SDK, but am unsure of proper implementation.  My question is, what is the most secure and user friendly method for accessing google services from within the application?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at Google Api Java Client, it's far from finished but it should work.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager